# Selecting no of images using multiselectgrid in Android

Tags: java, android, android-gridview

i have designed app where i have used mulitiselectgridview for image selection.my requirement is i want to restrict user to select max 8 images, means whenever a user try to chek on the 9th element it should display a warning message as popup i.e max 8 images can be selected and that 9th images should be autometically unchecked.

```
public class MultiImagePicActivity extends Activity {

GridView mGrid;


private String[] arrPath,modifiedArrayPath;
private int ids[];
private int count;
int selectCount;
Activity act=this;
List<String> imagepaths;
int maximageselection;
//int sel=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //now get Intent Extras




    imagepaths=new ArrayList<String>();
    imagepaths.clear();
    loadApps();

    setContentView(R.layout.grid_1);
    mGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.myGrid);

    mGrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapterxtends());

    mGrid.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    mGrid.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener());

}

    private void loadApps() {

    final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,      MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
    Cursor imagecursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null, orderBy);
    int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
    this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
    ids = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0; i <this.count; i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        ids[i] = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }

    imagecursor.close();

}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
    super.onBackPressed();

}
public class ImageAdapterxtends extends BaseAdapter{
    CheckableLayout l;
    ImageView i;
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arrPath.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arrPath[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (convertView == null) {
            i = new ImageView(MultiImagePicActivity.this);
            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            i.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(50, 50));
            l = new CheckableLayout(MultiImagePicActivity.this);
            l.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(
                    GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            l.addView(i);
        } else {
            l = (CheckableLayout) convertView;
            i = (ImageView) l.getChildAt(0);
        }
//          Bitmap bmp =      Utility.getResizedBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(arrPath[position]), 50, 50);
//          i.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        try {
            setBitmap(i, ids[position]);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
        }
        return l;

    }


    }

    private void setBitmap(final ImageView iv,final int id) {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
            Bitmap myBitmap;
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                //iv.setImageBitmap(result);
                setMyBitmap(result);
            }
            public final void setMyBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

                  if (this.myBitmap != null) {
                    this.myBitmap.recycle();
                  }
                  this.myBitmap = bitmap;
                  iv.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
                  iv.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
                  iv.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                }
        }.execute();
    }





public class CheckableLayout extends FrameLayout implements Checkable {
    private boolean mChecked;

    public CheckableLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {

        mChecked = checked;
        setForeground(checked ? getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tr) : null);
        }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    public void toggle() {
        //sel--;
        selectCount--;
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

}

public class MultiChoiceModeListener implements
        GridView.MultiChoiceModeListener {
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu for the CAB
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
        //return true;
        mode.setTitle("Select Items");
        mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        // Respond to clicks on the actions in the CAB
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_ok:
            Intent i = new Intent();
                modifiedArrayPath=imagepaths.toArray(new String[imagepaths.size()]);
                i.putExtra("selectedImagepath", modifiedArrayPath);
                //i.putExtra("data", selectedPath);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(a),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //TODO do your stuff here
                //mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                act.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text", 1);
    }

    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
            long id, boolean checked) {
        selectCount = mGrid.getCheckedItemCount();
        if(checked){
            imagepaths.add(arrPath[position]);
            if(selectCount>8){
                imagepaths.remove(arrPath[position]);
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MultiImagePicActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Restriction")
                .setMessage("Max 8 images are allowed!!!")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new         DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                        // continue with delete
                        //finish();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                 })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                 .show();

                selectCount=maximageselection;
            }
        switch (selectCount) {
        case 1:
            mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
            break;
        default:
            mode.setSubtitle("" + selectCount + " items selected");
            break;
        }
        }
        else
            imagepaths.remove(arrPath[position]);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Try to maintain one count variable and whenever user select any image just check this count and do some action base on count  also update count when if image selected less than 9.

Comment: i know that..as you can see that i have tried that logic in my code also.but i am not able unchek image after max image selection limit reached.can you please tell me where i have to modify my code